# (Pause) Stop download without dropping connection

Tags: c#

I want to be able to pause a download. I can stop them by dropping the existing connections.

What I'm referring to is almost similar to what's described here: https://superuser.com/questions/170509/whats-the-difference-in-using-pause-stop-in-%C2%B5torrent

My download class:

```
public class Download
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> DownloadStatusChanged;
    public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> DownloadProgressChanged;
    public event EventHandler DownloadCompleted;

    public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true

    public void DownloadFile(string DownloadLink, string Path)
    {
        stop = false; // always set this bool to false, everytime this method is called

        long ExistingLength = 0;
        FileStream saveFileStream;

        if (File.Exists(Path))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
            ExistingLength = fileInfo.Length;
        }

        if (ExistingLength > 0)
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        else
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.AddRange(ExistingLength);

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                long FileSize = ExistingLength + response.ContentLength; //response.ContentLength gives me the size that is remaining to be downloaded
                bool downloadResumable; // need it for sending empty progress

                if ((int)response.StatusCode == 206)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Resumable");
                    var downloadStatusArgs = new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs();
                    downloadResumable = true;
                    downloadStatusArgs.ResumeSupported = downloadResumable;
                    OnDownloadStatusChanged(downloadStatusArgs);
                }
                else // sometimes a server that supports partial content will lose its ability to send partial content(weird behavior) and thus the download will lose its resumability
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Resume Not Supported");
                    ExistingLength = 0;
                    var downloadStatusArgs = new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs();
                    downloadResumable = false;
                    downloadStatusArgs.ResumeSupported = downloadResumable;
                    OnDownloadStatusChanged(downloadStatusArgs);
                    // restart downloading the file from the beginning because it isn't resumable
                    // if this isn't done, the method downloads the file from the beginning and starts writing it after the previously half downloaded file, thus increasing the filesize and corrupting the downloaded file
                    saveFileStream.Dispose(); // dispose object to free it for the next operation
                    File.WriteAllText(Path, string.Empty); // clear the contents of the half downloaded file that can't be resumed
                    saveFileStream = saveFileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite); // reopen it for writing
                }

                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];
                    int byteSize = 0;
                    long totalReceived = byteSize + ExistingLength;
                    var sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    while ((byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
                        totalReceived += byteSize;

                        var args = new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs();
                        args.BytesReceived = totalReceived;
                        args.TotalBytesToReceive = FileSize;
                        float currentSpeed = totalReceived / (float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                        args.CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
                        if (downloadResumable == true)
                        {
                            args.ProgressPercentage = ((float)totalReceived / (float)FileSize) * 100;
                            long bytesRemainingtoBeReceived = FileSize - totalReceived;
                            args.TimeLeft = (long)(bytesRemainingtoBeReceived / currentSpeed);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //args.ProgressPercentage = Unknown;
                            //args.TimeLeft = Unknown;
                        }
                        OnDownloadProgressChanged(args);

                        if (stop == true) 
                            return;
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                }
            }
            var completedArgs = new EventArgs();
            OnDownloadCompleted(completedArgs);
            saveFileStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            saveFileStream.Dispose();
            return; //not needed because this is the last line of the method, but let's keep it here
        }
    }

    public void StopDownload()
    {
        stop = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadStatusChanged(DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> handler = DownloadStatusChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> handler = DownloadProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDownloadCompleted(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = DownloadCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool ResumeSupported { get; set; }
}

public class DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public long BytesReceived { get; set; }
    public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; set; }
    public float ProgressPercentage { get; set; }
    public float CurrentSpeed { get; set; } // in bytes
    public long TimeLeft { get; set; } // in seconds
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Note: I can already resume downloads, that's not what I want, if you were wondering.

Comment: `that's not what I want, if you were wondering`... OK then, what *do* you want?

Comment: To pause a download without dropping the connection to the server for a time being. To stop is to terminate all connections to the server you're downloading from. To pause is to retain connections to the server you're downloading from until you're automatically disconnected from it. To retain connections to the server without having to re-establish them, when you're not downloading the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code (you should copy it into your question, by the way), you have a loop that reads bytes from a stream. You have a flag that will stop the loop.

You do the exact same thing except for pausing instead of stopping. It could be another flag, but you will also need to know when to resume, so you need something for the loop to *wait* on. One fairly neat way to do this would be with a lock (mutex).

I don't know C# so I can't give you working code, but here is pseudocode for it. With your pointer to [the reference docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading(v=vs.110).aspx), it looks like [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) is the simplest thing suitable for this purpose.

```
bool stop = false
bool paused = false
SemaphoreSlim pauseLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1)

method download():
  while (stuff to read):
    read from stream
    write to file

    if stop:
       break

    // This will do nothing if not paused, or will block if paused
    pauseLock.Wait()
    pauseLock.Release()

method stop():
  stop = true
  self.unpause()  // stop waiting on lock if needed

method pause()
  if not paused:
    paused = true
    // Note this cannot block for more than a moment
    // since the download thread doesn't keep the lock held
    pauseLock.Wait()

method unpause()
  if paused:
    paused = false
    pauseLock.Release()
```

Of course, doing this may cause the server to drop your connection eventually (at which point you need to resume anyway, and you'll only notice this after unpausing).

Comment: The C# equivalent to release() is ReleaseMutex(). But I can't seem to know which one is acquire(). Is it WaitOne()? Can you let me know? Here are the Mutex methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's definitely not WaitOne().

Comment: @Expenzor It looks like Mutex is massive overkill because it uses kernel resources. I just updated my answer with something I think will work (a semaphore with count 1). There's quite likely to be something even more suitable for this purpose, but as I said, I don't actually know C#.

Comment: Okay, now that is really cool. When you see it in action. Thank you!